# List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> is deprecated

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I'm getting this error when I try to reiterate over a DropdownMenuItem

```
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> list = new List();

  _powers.forEach((power) {
    list.add(DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(power),
      value: power,
    ));
  });

  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `[]` to declare empty `List`

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> list = []; // change here

  _powers.forEach((power) {
    list.add(DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(power),
      value: power,
    ));
  });

  return list;
}
```

Comment: I changed but the error persisted, but I fixed it, I put a default value in variable and it worked correctly, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=default_list_constructor#default_list_constructor):

> The default ‘List’ constructor isn’t available when null safety is enabled.

So, in your case where you don't care about the list size you should use the list literal `[]`:

```
 List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> list = [];
```

Other suggestions include using the other List constructors, which can be seen [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html).

Comment: I changed but the error persisted, but I fixed it, I put a default value in variable and it worked correctly, thank you for your help